# Parallel Execution of python code - XML Parsing using XSLT

Tags: python, xslt, xml-parsing, lxml

I am new to python and have been trying to transform a XML file using XSLT.We are using multiple XSLT to process the XML file and convert to csv

```
def main(argv):
     
        /*Only Part of code is pasted*/

    while i < len(xslfile) and i < len(outfile):
    
        xsl = ET.parse(xslfile[i])
        transform = ET.XSLT(xsl)        
        newdom = transform(xml)
     
        with open(outfile[i], 'wb') as f:
           
            f.write(newdom)
          
        i += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Input will be :
"xml.py -x "XMLFILENAME" -s "firstxsl.xsl" -o  "firstcsv.csv" -s "secondxsl.xsl" -o  "secondcsv.csv"

is there any best way to run the parsing of firstxsl and secondxsl in parallel ?

sample xslt

This is the master event xslt

```
   
  <xsl:for-each select="Collection/List/Event">
       <xsl:value-of select="position()"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$var1"/> <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="srvid"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="acct"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="comm"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="stat"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="acct"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="test"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="flg"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="plan"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="state"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="id"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="grpid"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="name"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="call"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="origin"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="use"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="address"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="callid"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="context"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="sertype"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="address1"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="rqt"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="time"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="info"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="tet1"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="test2"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="test3"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="RoundingAmount"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="UsageRoundingAmount"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="UsageRoundingAmountUnit"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Agg"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="IniId"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="IniExId"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="IniDeviceId"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="DeviceExternalId"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Flags"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="WalId"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="WalOwnerId"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="WalExternalId"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Tax"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="TaxCert"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="TaxLoc"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="EventT"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Dur"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="EventId"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Date"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Center"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="AuthEventId"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Del"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="VersionId"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="PrimaUserId"/> <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="PrimUserExtrId"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="InitiatorType"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="WalOwnerType"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="tag"/>  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="area"/>
```

Comment: there is no problem with the code . we are processing huge XML file and each file is taking almost 2 mins to process. so was thinking if we can execute in parallel

Comment: How big is "huge"? 2 minutes is an incredibly long time. Do you know why it's taking so long? Because you shouldn't be looking at performance tuning until you know why the code is so slow.

Comment: Thanks Michael.i have a XML with around 26 array in it . so i created 26 XSLT to read the XML .so to read 10 XML file with around 5 MB files its taking 2 min

Comment: The Master Event which have around 23 varaibles in it is taking 9 seconds to read around 22852 records

Comment: i have attached the sample master event xslt in the question . is it reasonable to take 9 seconds for reading 23 thousand records?

Comment: No, this is absurdly slow. Something is wrong somewhere. Unfortunately, with problems like this, it's hard to include the relevant information in your question until you know what the problem is.

Comment: thanks.is there any way way to find out which particular tag reading taking more time .apologies if my question is absurd .am still trying to understand XSLT

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what instrumentation is available in the XSLT processor you are using (which you haven't actually identified). You could try running it in Saxon and instrumenting it with -TP:profile.html on the command line, but the performance would probably be completely different.